# How to fix exception MethodAccessException during file reading?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7, filereader

I have to read a text file which added in my project DataMid/Bigram_MidWord.txt where DataMid is a folder and Bigram_MidWord.txt is a file to read.
When i write the statement

`FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"/SourceCode,component/DataMid/Bigram_MidWord.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);`

then i get the exception as follows:
`Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess)`

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What Build Action have you set for the file?

Comment: Build Action is resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use `FileStream` to access a resource that is embedded in your application's XAP file. `FileStream` is used for accessing the file system (e.g. isolated storage).

To access a text file that is a resource in your XAP file, you can use the following code:

```cs
string text;
Uri uri = new Uri("("/AssembyName;component/DataMid/Bigram_MidWord.txt", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
StreamResourceInfo sri = App.GetResourceStream(uri);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sri.Stream);
text= sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
```

Comment: i tried to do that but ResourceInfo is not recognized in my visual studio 2010.

Comment: Apologies, it should have read `StreamResourceInfo`. I've corrected my answer now.

Comment: i tried that but don't know why i m getting sri as null . I also tried it by making text file build action as resource.

Comment: @rubyraj Since it is added as resource you have to use `Uri uri = new Uri("/AssembyName;component/DataMid/Bigram_MidWord.txt", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);` make sure to change AssemblyName with name of your assembly.

Comment: @rubyraj I think you can also use `Uri uri = new Uri("../DataMid/Bigram_MidWord.txt", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);`.But not Tested