# Open a local xml file in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

Me having a local xml file and need to load it to Isolated Storage when my app. starts for first time. but if i am opening that file using stream OR File.Open it's throwing an error.
Also i need to store that file in serialized form. Please help, as being new to WP7 and C# not able to crack it.

Following code is used for opening the XML file:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("site.xml", FileMode.Open);
```

Comment: Can you explain your situation a bit more? Do you have this file already on the device? Or is it in your application project?  Do you want to save it to isolated storage?

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: Yes, the file is in application project and i need to store it in Isolated Storage. But whenever i opene that file and run the app. an exception is thrown like "Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode)"

Comment: You should post the code you're using to open the file with.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is a part of your project then you can add the file to your project as resource. That means file **"Build Action"** of the file should be **"Resource"**. And the following function can read the file from project resource.

```
Stream stream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.FileName.FileExtentation");
```

Now you can read the stream according to the file type. If it is a XML file then you can read it like below.

**As an example**

```
XElement element = XElement.Load(stream);
foreach (XElement phraseElement in element.Elements())
{
    MyClass foo = new foo();
    foreach (XAttribute attribute in phraseElement.Attributes())
      foo.Text = attribute.Value;

}
```

**How to write to isolated storage and read a file from isolated storage? Please check out the following link**

http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2010/09/03/Using-Isolated-Storage-on-Windows-Phone-7.aspx

Also you can checkout the link below regarding Local Data Storage for Windows Phone.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626522%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the FileAccess mode as well for any Content type resource, since you can't open it in write-mode.

Try change your code to:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("site.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Also, see this question: [How to fix exception MethodAccessException during file reading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458663/how-to-fix-exception-methodaccessexception-during-file-reading)

Comment: Me opening a "Content" file site.xml as follows;FileStream stream = new FileStream("site.xml", FileMode.Open);