# Read files with Build Action = Content

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have some files in my project that have `Build Action` set to `Content`.

How can I obtain a stream to read these content files?

PS: Setting the `Build Action` to `Resource` and then reading the file via `Application.GetResourceStream()` is not an option.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252435/open-a-local-xml-file-in-wp7

Comment: @lukas - I think they're different enough that it's not a true dupe, even though it covers the same material.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Items with `Build Action` of `Content` are included in the package (.xap) file and are accessible via a `Uri`. You still use `Application.GetResourceStream()` to get at a stream

```cs
var si = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("FileName.ext", UriKind.Relative));
using (var sr = new StreamReader(si.Stream))
{
    //blah
}
```

This is fairly well documented in the MSDN help. [Application.GetResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can see a [full sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Accessing-files-sent-with-4b429e23) in the MSDN Code Gallery I posted recently, showing how to access files deployed along with the application by using the [Application.GetResourceStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method.